# React native string variable as a state key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state component like this -

```
this.state = {
        data: {machine_mode:'', machine_status:'', total_cycles: 0, current_cycle: 0}
      };
```

Also I am having string variables like this -

```
recKey = 'machine_mode';
recVal = 'Auto';
```

Now I want to update state with key as recKey. I tried something like this -

```
this.setState({data:{...this.state.data, [recKey]: recVal}});
```

It fails to update state.

If I write like -

```
this.setState({data:{...this.state.data, machine_mode: recVal}});
```

I get expected results. That means a value in a variable works fine but if a key is in a variable, it fails to update.

Please help me to deal with this issue.

Comment: Well it should work. Are you sure that you are checking the right way? Add some `console.log` calls to see what the data is, before and after update.

Comment: what's the state before and after this code executes?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but state holds same value e.g. machine_mode remains '' even after state update. I have used console.log for checking -

console.log('data: ', this.state.data.machine_mode);

Comment: it should work as expected, state updates are asynchronous so try logging like this.
  ```const recKey = 'machine_mode';
   const recVal = 'Auto';
   console.log('prev state', this.state.data )
   this.setState({data:{...this.state.data, [recKey]: recVal}},()=>{ 
    console.log('After update', this.state.data )
    });```

Comment: Thank you so much for all comments. It's working. Sorry! it was my mistake I forgot to mention from where I am getting data into string. Actually I am receiving it over bluetooth. As it is serial data, it was getting received along with delimiter '\r\n'. I removed that delimiter and it's working now.